# Entity framework 6.1 migrations error

Tags: entity-framework, entity, entity-framework-migrations

Hello i am trying to enable migrations in a multi context project. Im getting this error:

**One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
Mellon.Pricing.RiskControl.Migrations.RetornoValidacao: : EntityType 'RetornoValidacao' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.**

The thing is that there is no such DBSet in the context.

Code is below:

```
 public partial class RiskControlContext : DbContext
 {
  public RiskControlContext()
  : base("RiskControlContext")
{
}

#region Repositorios

IDbSet<DeParaCurvas> _deParaCurvas;
public IDbSet<DeParaCurvas> DeParaCurvas
{
  get { return _deParaCurvas ?? (_deParaCurvas = base.Set<DeParaCurvas>()); }
}

IDbSet<DeParaPrecos> _deParaPrecos;
public IDbSet<DeParaPrecos> DeParaPrecos
{
  get { return _deParaPrecos ?? (_deParaPrecos = base.Set<DeParaPrecos>()); }
}

IDbSet<PrecoRiskControl> _precoRiskControl;
public IDbSet<PrecoRiskControl> PrecoRiskControl
{
  get { return _precoRiskControl ?? (_precoRiskControl = base.Set<PrecoRiskControl>()); }
}

IDbSet<VerticeRiskControl> _verticeRiskControl;
public IDbSet<VerticeRiskControl> VerticeRiskControl
{
  get { return _verticeRiskControl ?? (_verticeRiskControl = base.Set<VerticeRiskControl>()); }
}

#endregion


protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  //Remover as conventions que não são usadas
  modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

  //Adiciona a configuração das entidades de maneira estruturada usando as classes 'TypeConfiguration' em Mapping
  modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new DeParaPrecosConfiguration());
  modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new DeParaCurvasConfiguration());
  modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PrecoRiskControlConfiguration());
  modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new VerticeRiskControlConfiguration());

}
```

}

Comment: Seems like you may need to review the objects in the physical database and search for `RetornoValidacao`. Is the error being raised during the initial migration? Or is it an update? If it is an update, are you certain there wasn't a key (field or object) created outside of your context?

Comment: Hi, this is the enable-migration commands.  the database itself does not exist

Comment: It seems like somewhow its adding DbSets to my context.

Comment: I recreated my domain objects as POCO  classes inside the migrations project i could get out of this error. But thats not what i want. It looks like it tries to map the other dependencies my objects have

Comment: the exception actually throws at: var dbMigrator = new DbMigrator(migratorConfig);

Comment: I have replaced each POCO for the actual businessrules class so i found out wich class is making the exception be thrown. I removed one lazy load that referenced antother project and got it to WORK ! but thats a big issue .

Answer (score 0):

i resolved this.  The error message was absolutely worng.

It was a problem with a lazy loading referencing another project in entity "DeParaPreco"  so i reaolved  by adding

this.Ignore(e => e.Ativo);

in the EntityTypeConfiguration